# How to filter Firebase events by custom parameters?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase for my app analytics and I'm having some issues with my events.

This event is fired when user opens a productDetailPage, with two parameters.

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventViewItem, parameters: [
    AnalyticsParameterSource: pageSource,
    AnalyticsParameterItemID: productId,
])
```

AnalyticsParameterItemID is the unique product id.

AnalyticsParameterSource is where the user comes from, like by sharing, pushNotification or promotion.

In my Firebase console, I'm able to see those events count. What I can't figure out is, how to just view the events of a specific product, or filter the events with AnalyticsParameterItemID == "specificProductId".

I'm pretty sure all those data is collected. I just can't find where to use those parameters. It seems I can only add audience as filters, not my event parameters.

I want to view the sources for a certain product for analyzing. Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You can simply log event with name and its value (Parameters).

Comment: @Maul Thank you for your reply! From my understanding, log event is used in Xcode console, not Firebase console? Or could you give me some instructions on how to do this?

Comment: We are also looking for a way to filter the events using custom parameter from within Firebase console with no luck. It seems like we have to link the app to BigQuery and write the queries manually to achieve this. Then export it to Google Studio in able to create a report. Seems overkill for a basic functionality that is already available in Google Analytics.

Answer (score -2):

As i m doing in my projects I simply Give event name its value and i can see that in firebase hope this is helpful to you

> My Code Snippet is in Objective-c

```
 NSDictionary *articleParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               <Value>, @"<Value_Name>",
                                               <Value>, @"<Value_Name>",
                                               nil];

[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"<event_Name>"
                                parameters:articleParams];
```

> In event name you can pass your product name dynamically. Hope this
>   will help to you..